# Auth0. How to prevent auto login

Tags: angular, authentication, auth0, autologin

If successfully logged in using password-login strategy login form not appear when trying to log in next times, but user automatically logging in. How to prevent this behavior? I want login form to appear every time after user log out.
I using Angular 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**:
When you clean local storage as shown in tutorials - you logged out from your app, but because of SSO you are still logged in on Auth0 side. To logged out compleatly you need to do redirection to "logout url" on Auth0. You can do something like that:
`document.location.href = 'https://[YOUR_APP_ON_AUTH0]/v2/logout?returnTo=http%3A%2F%2F[YOUR_APP_HOME_PAGE]'`
Also you need to fill **Allowed Logout URLs** [here](https://manage.auth0.com/#/tenant/advanced)  and **Allowed Logout URLs** in your application settings.

Comment: I have done what you suggest, and it still doesn't work. I even get "Successful logout" in Auth0 logs, but still the app logs me straight in again after logout. So i think there must be something more that need sot be done for this to work.

Comment: you should remember to fill all necessary fields (Allowed Logout URLs) on Auth0 Dashboard. For example for development I using 'http://localhost:4200", so I need to put it in "Allowed Logout URLs" fild.

Comment: Been looking all over the internet, this works perfectly. Thank you